# PHP conditional assistance

Tags: php

Hoping to get some help with adding a condition to this loop

The current code is working but there is an assumption that the data i am trying to collect is under `[0]` however after some testing i found this is not the case and i need to check all items `[0], [1], [2]`.. difficult to explain so please refer to the image below for step by step clarification.

```
$count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][0]['extnValue']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
     if(array_key_exists('dNSName', $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][0]['extnValue'][$i])) {
        $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][0]['extnValue'][$i]['dNSName'];
        $item = $i;
        echo 'DNSName',$item,'   : ', $value,"\n";
    }
}
```

Here is a visual of what the condition needs to do.

[image]

P.S. i am not a php expert so i will need your help to write the code.

- UPDATE (SEMI WORKING CODE) -

```js
    $extensions = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions']);
    for($j = 0; $j < $extensions; $j++) 
    {
    $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
         if(array_key_exists('dNSName', $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i])) {
            $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i]['dNSName'];
            $item = $i;
            echo 'DNSName',$item,'   : ', $value,"\n";
        }
    }
 }
```

-- CERTIFICATE --

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

-- UPDATE 2 (Current output) --

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Surround that code by

```
$extensions = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions']);
for($j = 0; $j < $extensions; $j++) 
{
   Existing code
}
```

And replace extensions[0] by extensions[j]

Comment: by adding your provided code, i am getting the data now but output is surrounded with errors as well.. `Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test3\parse_cert_dn.php on line 138`

Comment: i updated my post to include the semi working code per your solution but still getting errors as well.. please take a look

Comment: for the first loop, i think it might be missing an if statement to say if extnID does not equal "id-ce-subjectAltName" then do nothing. As it is now, i think the code is trying to return values from all items [0], [1] etc but it doesnt exist

Comment: That is what the yellow box is saying.  If that doesn't work then use var_dump(variable) to see what the data actually is.

Comment: i updated my post with the actual certificate i am trying to read the data from. You can use that to replicate exactly whats being returned.. please copy the certificate code and go to this link: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/decoder.php - paste the certificate code in the box and click on decode

Comment: wasnt sure how to use the var_dump .. but if you copy the code and paste it in the link provided you will see even better

Comment: by the way i just realised i made a typing error in  my screenshot.. step 4 should be if "id-ce-subjectAltName" is not found within extnID NOT extnValue

Comment: I updated my post to include a picture of the current output .. the green section is perfect! i am getting the data i want... but then there is errors in the red section. Need to get rid of the errors. Hope the picture helps

Comment: I think some of your data is null.  You just have to check for it.

Comment: thx Rohit. i don't know how to do that, sorry i am new to php. is it a quick fix to the existing code?

Comment: tried a few things and couldn't work out where to check for null. We are so close to resolving this. would you mind a quick chat?

Comment: I have accepted your assistance as the solution to my question. I am getting all the values as requested but I will start a new post to get help on ignoring null values. thx for all your help