# handle null values to prevent errors while in loop

Tags: php

I am using the following code to return data from a loop and although I am receiving the data it seems there may be null data also which is producing errors.

Here is the code

```
$extensions = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions']);
for ($j = 0; $j < $extensions; $j++) {
    $count = count($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (array_key_exists('dNSName', $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i])) {
            $value = $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i]['dNSName'];
            $item = $i;
            echo 'DNSName',$item,'   : ', $value,"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result of output

[image]

Can someone help me update the code to check for null values (i think in the first for loop) and ideally ignore those so the warnings don't appear? I am happy to provide more context if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `if` condition so that it checks if it is set and if it is array first:

```
if(isset($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i])
    &&
is_array($cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i])
    && 
array_key_exists('dNSName', $cert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][$j]['extnValue'][$i]))
```

if it detects in first condition it is not set or is not an array, it will not proceed to `array_key_exists` function.

Comment: i replaced it exactly like you have it and i get a strange error `
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test3\parse_cert_dn.php on line 154`

Comment: apparently you used one extra `{` curly brace, check if they pair up.

Comment: yep, i did.. wow almost all errors gone! i just see this now `Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test3\parse_cert_dn.php on line 139`

Comment: OK, I added one condition, if `isset`, now no more errors.

Comment: n-dru, haha, you are seriously good at this! you are right, all errors gone and i still get the data i need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The error probably is, because the incoming data has not indexes like 0,1,2,3... - may be it starts from 1.
The easest solution I think is if you replaces FOR structures by FOREACH.

Comment: it always starts with 0. you can see here more details [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713284/php-conditional-assistance/)